# How do you solve for x in an equation with 'Ceiling'

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this equation

$ Ceiling[(r + x) - z (r + x)] - ((r + x) - z (r + x)) = x$

I'm trying to solve for the value of $x$, but I'm not sure how to do this since $x $is also inside the Ceiling function.

Is there a way I can find the value of $x$ given only the values of $z $ and $ r$.

If you could even point me in the right direction that would be helpful, this is my first time dealing with ceiling functions in equations.

Comment: what are other variables than $x$

Comment: you have to consider two type of cases on where exprresion is whole no & other where no is not a whole no

Comment: z and r are real numbers. I guess anything would be helpful so long as the equation balances out.